# google calendar v3 api with OAuth 2.0 service account return empty result

Tags: calendar, oauth-2.0, google-api, is-empty, service-accounts

I got zero results from Calendar EventsResource.ListRequest with ServiceAccountCredential. And same code works properly with UserCredential. I don't get any exception or error, just the Events.Items count is always zero when I try to auth with key.p12 file.

I also set up the API client access for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar on the clientID of this service account in domain admin security setting.

Any ideas? Thanks

--------------------------------Here is my code:

```
    static UserCredential getUserCredential()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly },
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("carol test")).Result;
        }
        return credential;
    }

    static ServiceAccountCredential getServiceAccountCredential()
    {
        //Google authentication using OAuth for single calendar
        string serviceAccountEmail = "xx...@developer.gserviceaccount.com";            
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"clientPrivateKey.p12", "notasecret",
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new
        ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes =
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        return credential;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the service.

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new
        BaseClientService.Initializer();
        //initializer.HttpClientInitializer = getUserCredential();
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = getServiceAccountCredential();
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Google Calendar Sample";
        CalendarService calservice = new CalendarService(initializer);


     List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents = new List<CalendarEvent>();
        try
        {
            EventsResource.ListRequest req = calservice.Events.List("primary");    // Is it correct to use "primary" as calendarID?
            req.TimeMin = new DateTime(2014, 12, 1);
            req.TimeMax = new DateTime(2014, 12, 6);
            req.SingleEvents = true;
            req.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
            Events events = req.Execute();  // always empty for ServiceAccount auth, but getting results for user credential auth

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  // didnot get exception either way
        }

    }
```

---

Value for events (When use UserCredential)

```
{Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Events}
AccessRole: "owner"
DefaultReminders: Count = 1
Description: null
ETag: "\"1417813280083000\""
Items: Count = 2
Kind: "calendar#events"
NextPageToken: null
NextSyncToken: null
Summary: "myemail@mydomain.net"
TimeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
Updated: {12/5/2014 1:01:20 PM}
UpdatedRaw: "2014-12-05T21:01:20.083Z"
```

---

Value for events (when use service account key.p12 auth)

```
{Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Events}
AccessRole: "owner"
DefaultReminders: Count = 0
Description: null
ETag: "\"1417747728066000\""
Items: Count = 0
Kind: "calendar#events"
NextPageToken: null
NextSyncToken: null
Summary: "xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
TimeZone: "UTC"
Updated: {12/4/2014 6:48:48 PM}
UpdatedRaw: "2014-12-05T02:48:48.066Z"
```

Comment: The problem is the my gmail account calendar is not shared with my service account. If I share my calendar manually with my service account, then everything works fine. I will create a new question on how to set calendar domain access for service account.

Comment: The answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326650/how-to-access-domain-users-calendar-using-service-account-in-net